# How to pass multiple values for query_serializer in swagger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, swagger

In the below code I am trying to give two values to  query_serializer , but it throws SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument, how to handle it ?

```
  class SampleView(APIView,LimitOffsetPagination):
  permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
  @swagger_auto_schema(
    query_serializer=SampleSerializer,PaginationSerializer,
    responses={status.HTTP_200_OK: UserCommentsSerializer(many=True), status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND:[]},
    operation_id="comments",
  )
```

Comment: I think you are giving two parameter to query_serializer?

Comment: yes i need to pass 2 parameter's with out any issues or any other ways to handle it